# Stream never ends

Tags: pyspark, stream

I am trying to use pyspark stream, from file - and for the test purpose sink to the file.

```
                 df = self._spark\
                    .readStream\
                    .schema(schema)\
                    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1)\
                    .option("header", False)\
                    .csv(seq_id)


                df.writeStream\
                    .format("csv")\
                    .option("path", "./test/")\
                    .option("header", True)\
                    .option("checkpointLocation", "./test/check/")\
                    .start()\
                    .awaitTermination()
```

And it just hangs forever, writing never ends (produces correct fiels and then just waiting)! Even file is constant and not changing.

So what am i doing wrong? How correctly finish writing on file terminate?